# Delete Billing information from "Print order" in Magento

Tags: magento

Trying to delete some of the informations from the "Print Order" generated after you lay an order in Magento. Can't find the template where I can change this in Magento CE 1.6.

Can someone point me to the right template file ? I have looked at `sales/orders/print.phtml` but any changes I make there are not visible on the front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it helps, if you enable the `Template path hints` in magento, which can be enabled in the backend under `System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Template Path Hints and/or Add Block Names to Hints`. This way you can see, which templates are involved creating your current side. This should point you to the template file for the print order.

Comment: Thanks, found the solution! :)